# How to convert .txt file into .template file in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, templates, text-files

I have template written in txt file and I want to convert it to .template file in visual studio 2010.

Comment: What's the type of your template ?

Comment: I have written some code in C# text file. This file I am using as template in my program to format another file. Now, I want this text file as .template file so that I can add this item in my visual studio solution.